# Clustering for Longitudinal data

Tags: cluster-analysis, panel-data, longitudinal

for my project I need to cluster unbalanced longitudinal data. So, for participants there are varying amount of responses:

[[Example of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HemLJ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6nEV.png)

I just can't really find information on how I am meant to treat this dataset and hopefully some of you can help me understand this. For clustering, do I need to transform in the dataset for a single row per participant_id, or can I leave it in its current form?

I am very used to having ML methods where a row is an observation and that's it, so I cannot really imagine a clustering algorithm being able to work with multiple rows of observations belonging to the same participant. Especially if the amount of rows varies per participant.

Moreover, how should I treat missing waves?

Any tips and ideas or links to information or related kaggle projects would be much appreciated! I am currently a bit stuck and can't really find out how to transform my data. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import cluster

df = pd.read_csv ('C:\\cities.csv')
print(df)

cities = df

# K-means clustering based on longitude-latitude
kmeans = cluster.KMeans(10)
kmeans.fit(cities[['longitude', 'latitude']])
labels = kmeans.labels_
plt.scatter(cities['longitude'], cities['latitude'], c=labels)
plt.show()
```

More details here.

https://github.com/ash-wicus-ml/Notebooks/blob/master/Clustering%20-%20Longitude%20Latitude%20Coordinates.ipynb